# Connection python/DBT snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have tried to connect to snowflake with python using the following code: (using as authenticator the EXTERNALBROWSER)

```
import snowflake.connector as sf

con = sf.connect(
user='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
account='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
authenticator='EXTERNALBROWSER',
warehouse = 'XXXXXXXX',
database = 'XXXXXX',
schema = 'XXXXXXXXX'
)
```

But in my console I get the following message:
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again..

I did not understand why I get this message with no open browser that will allow me to connect to snowflake

I also get the same message when I have try to connect to snowflake using DBT.
I have try to allow pop-ups on any browser I have on my computer, but It did not change anything

I tried to connect to snowflake using python or DBT with SSO connection, but it does not open any pop up

Comment: No idea if it is case-sensitive but the documentation says the parameter is "externalbrowser" not "EXTERNALBROWSER"

Answer (score 0):

I was running into similar problems. Here's how I solved it (hopefully it helps) ->

- 'account' -> this should be identified using the URL (if you are using the classic Snowflake console, and not their newer snowsight SQL editor/writer). You can also see this link [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier)
- 'user' -> this should be copied exactly as it is setup by your admin. When you are logged into Snowflake, go to the top right, click your name -> preferences -> then look for 'Login Name'. Copy it exactly (case sensitive).